# XSD assert test for null values

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.1

I'm using XSD 1.1 to validate incoming XML.  I have an assert that works properly except when the values are null.

Here's the test:

```
<xs:assert test="ELEM1 = ' ' and ELEM2 = ' '
    or ELEM1 != ' ' and matches(ELEM2, '.*')"/>
```

Here's what the XML in question shows:

```
<ELEM1 />
<ELEM2 />
```

I've tried `"is null"`, `"is nil"`, `"= null"`, `"= nil"`, but nothing seems to work.

How do I test for a null element?

Comment: There is no such thing as "null" in XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Terminology note:** The elements, `ELEM1` and `ELEM2`, are generally referred to as being *empty* rather than having *null* values.

This `xs:assert`,

```
<xs:assert test="ELEM1[not(node())] and ELEM2[not(node())] "/>
```

says that there must be two empty child elements, `ELEM1` and `ELEM2`.